# Can three distinct points in the plane always be separated into bounded regions by four lines?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

How can I show that for any three points in the plane, four lines can be drawn that separate the three points into distinct enclosed regions?

Can any six points be enclosed in distinct regions formed by five lines?

Clarifications:

Points are distinct, enclosed regions mean bounded regions.

Thank you.

Comment: any three points in the plane? in that case you could consider that the points are at the same place.

Comment: It's easy if the three points lie on a line. Perhaps by a fractional linear transformation we can always reduce to this case?

Comment: @GerryMyerson If we do that then won't some of the lines be mapped to circles? Or is there a way around that?

Comment: @Joseph, good point. I was thinking circles would be the exceptional case, and that a small perturbation would get us back to lines, but I don't know why I was thinking that.

Comment: It's tedious, but I can see a relatively straightforward constructive proof by cases.

Comment: This guy, Intelligence has been posting SUMaC 2013 questions over the past some weeks, which have been answered by other people. His actual name is Pushkar Mishra, and he's applying for SUMaC. He was actually spotted posting the questions here: http://tinyurl.com/b4hnw2e and was caught (see the last answer on the link) but he changed his username that day to Intelligence. This post was then locked. SUMaC moderators, hope you see this, and StackExchange people, do something about it.

Comment: @Integral: "three points in the plane" is unambiguous $-$ the three points must be distinct. Otherwise there wouldn't be three of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I think this works. By scaling and rotation, we can assume that two of the points are $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Then the other point is $(x,y)$. Now the problem can be solved if the third point is $(1,0)$, with something like

[image]

Now if $x\ne 0$, the linear transformation $A=\pmatrix{x&0\\y&1}$ maps the point $(0,1)$ to $(x,y)$ and fixes the other two points, and also maps each green line to some new line, so $A$ applied to each line gives you four lines which enclose the points $(0,1), (0,0)$ and $(x,y)$.

If the third point is collinear with the other two points then it is easy to come up with the four lines that work.

[image]

Just make a cone that contains the two top points and another which contains the two bottom points. Then only the middle point will be in the intersection of the cones.

Comment: Nicely done.${}$